# Samsung Galaxy Store Sellers Portal - How to modify "VersionCode" for Tizen app

Tags: tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-studio

When I try to upload a beta version of a Tizen wearable app to the Samsung Galaxy Store Sellers Portal, I get an error:

> The VersionCode is invalid. VersionCode must be entered in integers and the same version number cannot be used for more than one binary.

I already have a beta up, and am trying to upload a newer beta for the same 1.0.0 version of the app.

In my tizen-manifest.xml file, I specify version="1.0.0" but I can't figure out how to specify a "VersionCode" or "Version Code".

```
<manifest xmlns="http://tizen.org/ns/packages" api-version="4" package="org.company.tizen.MyCoolTizenApp" version="1.0.0">
```

My current beta shows what you see in the image below when you view it in the Samsung Galaxy Store Sellers Portal.

[image]

How does one set the "Version Code" for a Tizen app? If it matters, I'm using Visual Studio to build a .NET based Tizen app.

For now I just have to delete the beta that's up and upload the new one that has the same "Version Code" that I'm unable to change. I can't find this documented anywhere, and searching through the depths of Samsung developer forums has not been helpful.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Nope. Tizen continues to be a dumpster fire for developers. Good thing Wear OS has been adopted by Samsung and Tizen for watches will die a slow death.

Answer (score 0):

It is alright, just change it to **1.0.1**

As far as I know, there is no way how to update it with the same code. This is the only way.

Answer (score -2):

It's just totally my inaccurate guess, but the error message possilbly refers the Version Name? not the Version Code.